# Disable HTTP when SSL is enabled

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, https

I've currently installed [tarang:Meteor-ssl-proxy](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl) as a separate node application. It enables me to access my meteor app via `https://` However, I'm still able to access the meteor app via it's default `localhost:3000` (or it's hostIP:3000 eg.: 1.2.3.4:3000)

How exactly do I disable direct access to the application via `3000`?

I've tried this with [force-ssl](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl) package, but it does nothing to force users from using https.

Here is my main.js of taranag-ssl:

```
~/experimental/Meteor-SSL-proxy$ cat main.js 

var PATH_TO_KEY = "/etc/ssl/server.key",
    PATH_TO_CERT = "/etc/ssl/server.crt";
    PATH_TO_CHAIN = "";

var fs = require('fs'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_KEY, 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_CERT, 'utf8'),
    //ca : fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_CHAIN, 'utf8')
  },
  target : "http://localhost:3000",
  ws: true,
  xfwd: true
};

var server = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options).listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use iptables to reject all outer access to port 3000 adding a rule like that using shell.

Check actual rules

```
iptables -nvL --line-numbers
```

Add a new rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP
```

I hope it helps.